# request.args.get() returns None

Tags: javascript, python, html

I am trying to  check the users input on my login form. 
I am sending an HTTP request to the server to check the database for the username.
Here is the network URL:
https://bceec5a5-eba3-49e3-b255-d3976d185fad-ide.cs50.xyz:8080/user_name?username=fabianomobono

Here's the html

```
 <form id="login_form" action='/home' method='post'>
        <input id="login_credentials_username" name='login_username' type='text' placeholder='Username' >
        <input id="login_credentials_password" name='login_password' type='password' placeholder="Password" >
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type='submit'>Log in</button>
      </form>
```

This is the JS code:

```
 $('#login_form').ready(function() {

    $('#login_form').on('submit', function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        logincheck();

    });
});

    function logincheck(){
        var username = document.getElementById("login_credentials_username").value;
        var password = document.getElementById("login_credentials_password").value;

        if (username == ''){
          alert("no user");
          return false;
        }
        else if (password == ''){
           alert('no password');
           return false;
        }

        else if (password && username){
            alert(password + username);
            console.log(username)
            $.get('/user_name?username' + username, function(r){
                if (r === false){
                    alert('python returned false');
                    return false;
                }

                else{
                    alert('python returned true');
                    return true;
                }

            });
            return false;

        }

      else {

        return true;
      }

         }
```

and here is the python function:

```
@app.route("/user_name", methods=["GET"])
def login_usercheck():
    print(Fore.GREEN + "user_check function, line 171")
    username = (request.args.get('login_username'),)
    print(username)
    conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username =?", username)
    old_user = c.fetchall()

    if len(old_user) > 0:
        return jsonify(True)

    else:
        return jsonify(False)
```

The problem is that my username variable in the python function always returns NULL. I tried all combinations of,(request.form.get, request.args.get... and so on)
Funny thing is I have a similar function to check for the register credentials and that one works just fine. I can't seem to figure out what the problem is...
Here's what I get in the terminal:

(None,)
192.168.164.98 - - [05/Nov/2019 17:54:01] "GET /user_name?username=cf HTTP/1.0" 200 -

Comment: can you add your get request URL from your network tab in browser. Seems like you are missing `=` parameter in your get request and just want to validate if it is get call itself is wrong or the backend logic.

Comment: https://bceec5a5-eba3-49e3-b255-d3976d185fad-ide.cs50.xyz:8080/user_name?username=fabianomobono

Comment: Did you mean that??

Comment: Here `'/user_name?username' + username` you need to add `=`. It should be `'/user_name?username=' + username`

Comment: I just tried it.... I still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

username = request.args.get('**username**')

$.get('/user_name?**username**' + username,...
the bold parts need to match 
it was pointed out to me by another user...